# SQLAlchemy+PostgreSQL update is not working

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

What I'm trying to do is to update an existing row in column dateofbirth with lineEdit(dobLine) value.

```py
dob = self.ui.dobLine.text()
conn = engine.connect()
trans = conn.begin()
conn.execute(
f"""UPDATE mytable SET dateofbirth = :dateofbirth", dateofbirth='{dob}' WHERE login='{l}'"""
)
trans.commit()
conn.close()
```

That returns a mistake in the update line

Comment: Do you want your WHERE clause to match the literal `'l'`, i.e., `WHERE login='l'` …?

Comment: Can you post what error you get?

Comment: Please include the error message inside your question.